# Extracting specific row from file windows command line

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have to combine csv files into 1 file using a batch file.

The problem is that I only need the third row from each file.

How can I extract a specific row from a csv file in the windows command line / batch file?

I have found skip as command to skip lines from start of file, but I need to also skip the files from after the line I need.

This is my current code (after converting from xls to csv):

```
for %%i in (headers.csv) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
)
for %%i in (file*.csv) do (
    for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
)
```

Comment: Do you only need row3 of one line or does the csv contain multiple lines you need?

Comment: I needed the first line (headers) and then the third line of the first file. And then only the third line of every other file, since we already have the headers. I went around that by creating a seperate file for the headers. And now all I needed was the third line. Both answers below solved my problem. Thank you for replying though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%i in (headers.csv) do (
 set "flag=Y"
 for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do if defined flag set "flag="&echo %%j >> combined.csv
)
for %%i in (file*.csv) do (
 set "flag=Y"
 for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do if defined flag set "flag="&echo %%j >> combined.csv
)
```

`flag` is set to something each time a new file is chosen. The first 2 lines of that file are then skipped, and on the third flag is cleared and the line reproduced. Once `flag` is cleared (becomed not-defined) the `echo` won't happen.

`if defined` works on the `current` (ie run-time) value of the variable, not the initial (parse-time) value.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('
            findstr /n "^" headers.csv file*.csv ^| findstr /r /c:"^[^:]*:3:"
        ') do (
            set "line=%%b"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo(!line:~2!
            endlocal
        )
    ) > combined.csv
```

It will use `findstr` to retrieve the full content from all the indicated files (I was not sure and I've also included the headers file), with lines numbered. As multiple files are requested, the output from this first `findstr` command will be in the format

```
filename.ext:lineNumber:linedata
```

This is filtered by a second `findstr` using a regular expression to only retrieve the third line from each file.

These lines will be processed by the `for` loop, using the colon as a delimiter to remove the file name. To avoid problems with lines that could start with a colon, the line number and the aditional colon are removed with a substring operation.

If in the final code the reference to the files forces `findstr` to include in the output the full path to the files, the `tokens` clause needs to be changed to `tokens=2,*` to face the colon in the drive name.

Comment: This worked, except for the file name being printed in the first row of the combined file. The tokens=2,* did not help for that. This was very helpfull though, thank you for the thourough explanation!

Comment: @LvS, what file name is printed in the first row? What is exactly inside the line?

Comment: The first line printed:
`code`
debnr,Naam,telefoon,naam1,,Straat,huisnr,Postcode,plaats,,Naam2,Land,levcond,referentie,Factuuradres E-mail,ap Land,AP detail,AP consigneefile(3).xls.csv:1:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
`code`
file(3).xls.csv was the first of 5 files that were combined, besides the headers.csv

Comment: and the names of the other files were not printed in the combined.csv, just only the first one.

Comment: @Lvs, as I read it, it is at the end of the line. It seems header line do not include a correct terminator and the first line in the next file is retrieved as a continuation.

Comment: yes, i checked the header file, you are right. Thank you!